# Why did my cat eat a bee, and then puke afterwards?

Tags: cats, health, eating

A couple weeks back, one of my cats, Odin, ate a bee. A lot was going on at that moment, I was getting ready for a new couch, and a friend was over. Then, while we were switching the couches, Odin threw up on the wood in the back porch outside. It seemed like a big problem, especially since everything was happening at once.

So, what was wrong? Why did he even eat the bee? I searched for an answer as to why he ate the bee, but there wasn't much information that I could find. My cat may have anxiety, or stress, or maybe pica. And that's really all I know.

So please help me. Why did he eat the bee in the first place? It just seems so weird. Could he have an illness?

Sometimes he eats things that are not food, and that are deadly, including string, poisonous plants, and that bee! Do cats even know it's bad for them?

Comment: Welcome, FH Jordan! I see that you already took the [tour] and I hope you found already the time to read [ask] and [answer]. Please note that the posts here should be less conversational as in the standard web forums you may be more familiar with. Could you please take a look at your post and streamline it a bit, so that the core question is clearer and important details not obscured by extra anecdotal details? You can always [edit] your post. The clearer your question, the better the answers you can get.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, while eating a bee itself is considered safe, **they can cause airway blockage if they sting**. Never let your cat play with bees and if you see he eats one, stay vigilant for 12 hours.

I have seen cats play and eat flies, butterflies, spiders and other insects. Cats are curious by nature and their eyesight is developed to follow moving objects. Therefore, moving insects stimulate cat's hunting instincts.

He probably ate the bee out of curiosity but his stomach did not agree with it. This looks like a solitary incident so I would not worry.

Cats eating plants, however, is a different issue. They usually eat plants to help them throw up. This might be due to a furball or due to some other factor causing an upset stomach. Cats might also eat plants by curiosity. I would not worry about this either.

That being said, you should get rid of your poisonous plants if you have a cat. I would definitely get rid of *Dieffenbachia* or *Lily of the valley* if you have one. You need to check other plants one by one. Since cats are much smaller in size and have a fast metabolism, any plant deemed dangerous for small children are also dangerous to cats.